# com.fatwire.wem.sso.SSOException: Failed to acquire TGT. HTTP response code 400

Tags: cas, http-status-code-400, fatwire, webcenter-sites

I am getting this kind of error while connecting to webcenter server through my java program. I debugged the code and found the login credentials correct

I checked the firewall setting for the VM where webcenter is installed. it's off.
What could be reason for getting bad request as 400 ? Any idea?

please help me out.

here is the stacktrace for your reference

```
com.fatwire.wem.sso.SSOException: Failed to acquire TGT. HTTP response code 400
    at com.fatwire.wem.sso.cas.CASProvider.getTGT(CASProvider.java:205)
    at com.fatwire.wem.sso.cas.CASProvider.getMultiTicket(CASProvider.java:163)
    at com.fatwire.wem.sso.SSOSession.getMultiTicket(SSOSession.java:155)
    at com.translations.globallink.webcenter.model.webservices.cs.CSService.getMultiticket(CSService.java:32)
    at com.translations.globallink.webcenter.model.webservices.cs.CSService.getSites(CSService.java:143)
    at com.translations.globallink.webcenter.model.service.impl.GloballinkCSServiceImpl.testCSConnection(GloballinkCSServiceImpl.java:370)
    at com.translations.globallink.webcenter.controller.GlConfigController.showGlConfigForm(GlConfigController.java:281)
    at com.translations.globallink.webcenter.controller.GlConfigController.submitCSConfigForm(GlConfigController.java:693)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.fatwire.wem.sso.cas.filter.CASFilter.doFilter(CASFilter.java:695)
    at com.fatwire.wem.sso.SSOFilter.doFilter(SSOFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be networking or proxy related?

See:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2506584?tstart=0

Cheers,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was:

Failed to acquire TGT. HTTP response code 500

The problem was that the content server was unstable, not shuted down but it didn´t respond.

I restarted content server and the connection went ok.

Hope this help.